# Error en operaciones TAD matriz C++

Tags: c++, clase

Estoy implementando unas operaciones para un TAD matriz, las operaciones son: suma, resta, multiplicación y trasponer.

La mayor parte del TAD viene ya programada en el ejercicio, solo tengo que definir e implementar esas operaciones.

El código es el siguiente:

En la cabecera:

```
#ifndef MATRIZ_HPP
#define MATRIZ_HPP

#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#define F 3
#define C 3

class Matriz
{
public:

  // Definición de las clases de excepciones
  class ECoordenadasIncorrectas: public std::runtime_error
  {
  public:
    ECoordenadasIncorrectas(const std::string& w = "ECoordenadasIncorrectas"): std::runtime_error(w) {}
  };

  Matriz();

  ~Matriz();

  float valor(int i, int j);

  void asignar(int i, int j, float v);

  template <typename ModificaElemento>
  void modificar(ModificaElemento modifica_elemento);

  Matriz& operator=(Matriz& m);

  /** Constructor de copia */
  Matriz(Matriz& m);

  bool operator==(Matriz& m);
  bool operator!=(Matriz& m);    

  //ESTA ES LA PARTE QUE YO ESTOY IMPLEMENTANDO
  void identidad();
  void ceros();
  void unos();
  void multiplicar(Matriz m, Matriz& salida);
  void sumar(Matriz m, Matriz& salida);
  void restar(Matriz m, Matriz& salida);
  void trasponer(Matriz& salida);
  int filas();
  int columnas();
  //HASTA AQUÍ
private:
  float elementos_[F][C];
};

// En las templates (TADs genéricos) hacemos la inclusión al revés el .cpp en el .hpp (para que
// al incluir el matrices.hpp vaya todo el código y se pueda hacer la instanciación de la
// template).
#include "matriz.cpp"
#include "matriz_io.cpp"

#endif // MATRIZ_HPP
```

El cpp de la entrada y salida del que no se puede tocar nada(viene hecho):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Matriz & m)
{
  os << m.filas() << " " << m.columnas() << std::endl;
  os << std::setprecision(4) << std::fixed;
  for(int i=1; i <= m.filas(); i++)
  {
    for(int j=1; j <= m.columnas(); j++)
    {
      os << m.valor(i,j) << " ";
    }
    os << std::endl;
  }

  return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Matriz& m)
{
  int filas, columnas;
  float v;

  is >> filas >> columnas;
  for (int i=1; i<=filas; i++)
  {
    for (int j=1; j<=columnas; j++)
    {
      is >> v;
      m.asignar(i,j,v);
    }
  }

  return is;
}
```

El cpp con la implementación de las operaciones(solo pongo las mías):

```
void Matriz::unos()
{
    for(int i=0; i<F; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
        {
            elementos_[i][j]=1;
        }
    }
}

int Matriz::columnas()
{
    return C;
}

int Matriz::filas()
{
    return F;
}

void Matriz::sumar(Matriz m, Matriz& salida)
{
    for(int i=0; i<F; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
        {
            salida.elementos_[i][j]+=m.elementos_[i][j];
        }
    }

}

void Matriz::restar(Matriz m, Matriz& salida)
{
    for(int i=0; i<F; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
        {
            salida.elementos_[i][j]-=m.elementos_[i][j];
        }
    }
}
void Matriz::multiplicar(Matriz m, Matriz& salida)
{
    for(int i=0; i<F; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<C;k++)
            {
                salida.elementos_[i][j]+=m.elementos_[i][k]*salida.elementos_[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
void Matriz::trasponer(Matriz& salida)
{
    for(int i=0; i<F; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
        {
            salida.elementos_[i][j]=salida.elementos_[j][i];
        }
    }
}
```

Y el main.cpp para probar todas las operaciones(pongo únicamente las que afectan a mis operaciones, todo viene hecho aquí):

```
#include "matriz.hpp"

#define Elemento float

#define MatrizPrueba Matriz


void probarCrearMatriz()
{
  MatrizPrueba m;
  std::cout << m;
}
void probarMultiplicar(std::istream& is)
{
  MatrizPrueba m1, m2, m3;

  is >> m1;
  is >> m2;

  m1.multiplicar(m2, m3);

  std::cout << m3;
}

void probarSumar(std::istream& is)
{
  MatrizPrueba m1, m2, m3;

  is >> m1;
  is >> m2;

  m1.sumar(m2, m3);

  std::cout << m3;
}

void probarRestar(std::istream& is)
{
  MatrizPrueba m1, m2, m3;

  is >> m1;
  is >> m2;

  m1.restar(m2, m3);

  std::cout << m3;
}

void probarTrasponer(std::istream& is)
{
  MatrizPrueba m1, m2;

  is >> m1;

  m1.trasponer(m2);

  std::cout << m2;
}
void probarUnos()
{
  MatrizPrueba m;
  m.unos();
  std::cout << m;
}
int main()
{
  char opcion;

  // Lectura de la operaci?n a probar
  std::cin >> opcion;

  try
  {
    switch(opcion)
    {
      case 'c':  probarCrearMatriz(); break;
      case 'i':  probarIdentidad(); break;
      case 'u':  probarUnos(); break;
      case 'z':  probarCeros(); break;
      case 'a':  probarAsignar(std::cin);  break;
      case 'v':  probarValor(std::cin); break;
      case 'm':  probarMultiplicar(std::cin); break;
      case 'r':  probarRestar(std::cin); break;
      case 's':  probarSumar(std::cin); break;
      case 't':  probarTrasponer(std::cin); break;
      case 'o':  probarModificar(std::cin); break;
      case 'C':  probarCopiar(std::cin); break;
      case '=':  probarIgual(std::cin); break;
      case 'D':  probarDestruir(std::cin); break;
    }
  }
  catch (std::exception const& excepcion)
  {
    std::cout << "EXCEPCION GENERADA: "  <<  excepcion.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

**El error** que no consigo solucionar es el siguiente:

Todas las operaciones que no sean mías excepto `unos` y `ceros` funcionan perfectamente, pero al llegar a las operaciones `suma` `resta` `multiplicacion` y `trasponer`, una de las matrices que tienes que introducir por teclado no se guarda, y en la `suma`, `resta` y `multiplicación` me imprime la 2ª matriz que introduzco por teclado(en vez del resultado de la operación de ambas matrices), en ´trasponer´ me imprime una matriz 3x3 de 0's.

¿Alguien puede ver el error? Yo seguiré buscando.

Comment: ¿Qué son "*operaciones TAD*"?

Comment: Las funciones u operaciones que constituyen el TAD matriz, las especifico en la parte pública de la clase. Es la jerga que utiliza el profesor en la asignatura y los apuntes xd.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster ¿puede que sea una configuracion del compilador o algo de mi pc? no tiene sentido no veo el error

Answer (score 0):

Al final di con la solución. Gracias a quien haya intentado buscar el error, es largo, pero bastante tonto.

Resulta que las funciones `suma` `resta` `multiplicacion` y `trasponer` reciben unos parámetros de entrada, entre los que se encuentra el parámetro ´salida´ que todos comparten.

Pues bien, este parámetro no recibe ninguna información de teclado, es simplemente para guardar el resultado de la matriz actual con la matriz m(el otro parámetro).

Conclusión, (solo hay que modificar esta parte del código) el código queda así:

```
//LA OPERACIÓN DEL BUCLE FOR(de cada función) ES LO CORREGIDO

void Matriz::sumar(Matriz m, Matriz& salida)
{
    for(int i=0; i<F; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
        {
            salida.elementos_[i][j]=elementos_[i][j]+m.elementos_[i][j];
        }
    }

}

void Matriz::restar(Matriz m, Matriz& salida)
{
    for(int i=0; i<F; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
        {
            salida.elementos_[i][j]=elementos_[i][j]-m.elementos_[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void Matriz::multiplicar(Matriz m, Matriz& salida)
{
    for(int i=0; i<F; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<C;k++)
            {
                salida.elementos_[i][j]+=elementos_[i][k]*m.elementos_[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}

void Matriz::trasponer(Matriz& salida)
{
    for(int i=0; i<F; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
        {
            salida.elementos_[i][j]=elementos_[j][i];
        }
    }
}
```

Simplemente era esta parte del código en el .cpp.
Correcciones bienvenidas.